# Parâmetros, funções em C

Tags: c, parâmetros, linha-de-comando

Pessoal sou iniciante em programação e tenho muita dúvida em relação à funcões e os parâmetros. Segue um código de exemplo:

```
#include math.h

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) // Dúvida nessa linha    
{           
    double x1, x2, y1, y2, d; 

    double v; 

    scanf("%lf, %lf, %lf, %lf", &x1, &y1, &x2, &y2); 

    v = (x1-x2)*(x1-x2) + (y1-y2)*(y12-*y2); 

    d = sqrt(v); 

    printf("Distância: %f", d); 

    return 0;     
}
```

Dúvida: o que estes parâmetros indicam nesse código? Quando e por quê devem ser usados os parâmetros?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Os parâmetros da função `main` permitem que se tenha acesso aos argumentos passados por linha de comando ao programa. Por exemplo, o programa de exemplo poderia ser modificado para receber os números do cálculo por linha de comando. Caso que queira que a chamada do programa seja:

```
> dist.exe 10 10 50 60
```

O programa poderia ser modificado assim:

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h> 

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) // Dúvida nessa linha    
{           
    double x1, x2, y1, y2, d; 

    double v; 

    x1 = atof( argv[1] );
    y1 = atof( argv[2] );
    x2 = atof( argv[3] );
    y2 = atof( argv[4] );

    if (argc != 5)
        printf("Erro: eram esperados 4 parâmetros");

    v = (x1-x2)*(x1-x2) + (y1-y2)*(y12-*y2); 

    d = sqrt(v); 

    printf("Distância: %f", d); 

    return 0;     
}
```

`argc` indica o número de argumentos de linha de comando, mais 1. Este mais 1 está ali porque o nome do próprio programa é levado em conta também.

`argv` é um array que contém os parâmetros em si. No exemplo de chamada anterior estes parâmetros seriam:

```
argc = 5;
argv = { "dist.exe", "10", "10", "50", "60" };
```

Answer (score 1):

argc (argument count) e argv (argument vector) são argumentos que são passados pela linha de comando para a função main em C e C++.
argc é a quantidade de string enviadas pela linha de comando e argv é onde as string estão contidas.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    printf("\nVoce passou %d elementos pela linha de comando.\n\n", argc);
    puts("Inprimindo os argumentos\n");
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < argc; i++) {
        printf("%s\n", argv[i]);
    }
    putchar('\n');
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Compilando o programa com o gcc na linha de comando do windows:

```
gcc HelloWorld.cpp -o HelloWorld
```

Após isso, será gerado o executável: HelloWorld.exe

Agora é só executar o executável HelloWorld.exe pela linha de comando e passar os argumentos

```
HelloWorld 10 20 30 Ola Test
```

Resultado:

```
Voce passou 6 elementos pela linha de comando.

Inprimindo os argumentos

HelloWorld
10
20
30
Ola
Test
```